# Can I cancel some files in IFileDialogEvents::OnFileOk with Multiple select?

Tags: c++, openfiledialog, filedialog

I was wondering if I can cancel some files selected from file dialogs?

This is the method I'm registered to:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775879(v=vs.85).aspx

I would like to do my custom validations, and the documentation says that I can return S_FALSE to cancel the opening.
If some files fail validation (my custom one) - I want to be able to continue opening just the valid ones.

Current situation, is that I delete the failed files and then the application (word/adobe) says that the file doesn't exist.

I prefer that it won't try to open them (to change the "selected files" somehow)

Is that possible?

Comment: You can't prevent the user from selecting files (apart from setting the file types filter). What you can do is open the files that you want, and display a message box explaining an error about the files that couldn't be opened.

Comment: @user1610015 thats exactly what i do, but the invalid files are still "opened" through WORD for example (because they were part of the selection in the OnFileOK)